# How to calculate angle bisectors and intersection points of them for a polygon to construct straight skeleton?

Tags: linear-algebra, angle, polygons

I am trying to construct staright skeleton of a polygon. I have coordinates array of polygon. How to construct angle bisectors of lines using coordinates? And then how can I calculate intersection point of 2 angle bisectors as in the picture?  [angle bisectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn0lz.png)

Comment: There is a conceptualy "easy way" to consider this kind of issue : seeing skeleton as the projection of limits of flat pieces of a roof. I am going to expand this idea in an anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can always translate as te coordinates so that your angle vertex is at the origin.  Then let the surrounding vertices be $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

First compute the distances which when divided into the lengths vf the vectors will give unit vectors:

$(a,b)\to r_1=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ then $(a',b')=(a/r_1,b/r_1)$

$(c,d)\to r_2=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ then $(c',d')=(c/r_2,d/r_2)$

From the resultant of unit vectors lying on the angle bisectors infer that this bisector passes through $(a'+c',b'+d')$.

Comment: Surprized to meet DDT here. Maybe for killing mathematical bugs...

Comment: Should be killing bugs with my phone.  Fingers are too fat for the tiny key areas and when I miss autocorrect goes postal.  Can I get a stylus that will work on a Samsung A50?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following picture where the initial convex polygon boundary is in red :

[image]

It represents the variations of function $z=d(x,y)$ defined as the (internal) **distance function to the boundary of the polygon**. The peak $(x_0,y_0,z0)$ is such that $(x_0,y_0)$ is the most internal point and $z_0$ is its closes distance to the polygon boundary.

The different planes $P_k$ that need to be considered are those that cross the horizontal plane along edges $E_k$ of the polygon with, say, a 45° inclination. Seeing the resulting surface as a roof constituted by different planar panes, the skeleton is, in a natural way, the projection of the panes' limits (locus of points whose distance to the border can be computed in two ways = pieces of angle bissectors : here we are...).

Mathematicaly, the above distance function is defined in this way :

$$d(x,y)=\min_k(f_k(x,y)) \ \text{where} \ z=f_k(x,y)$$

is the equation of the $k$th plane.

For a fully automatic obtention of the skeleton in a general case, one has to keep track of the "right planes at the right place" by using a hierarchical organisation, proceeding inward, from the border, keeping track of which plane is still "active" at such and such distance, until there is ... no longer any active plane.

Here is the Matlab program that I have conceived for such a picture, providing in particular the exact plane equations.

> ```
> x=[0,3,5,7,8,6,3,0,0];y=[0,0,1,3,7,8,7,3,0];
> L=length(x)-1;
> plot(x,y,'r','linewidth',2);
> [X,Y]=meshgrid(0:0.01:8,0:0.01:8);
> Zc=10*ones(size(X));hold on;
> Z1=zeros(size(X));
> for k=1:L
>    vx=x(k+1)-x(k);vy=y(k+1)-y(k);
>    Vx=vx/norm([vx,vy]);Vy=vy/norm([vx,vy]);
>    xm=(x(k+1)+x(k))/2;ym=(y(k+1)+y(k))/2;
>    P=[xm-Vy,ym+Vx,sqrt(1/2)]';% normal vect. to plane P_k
>    M=[x(k),x(k+1);y(k),y(k+1)];
>    dd=det([[M,[P(1);P(2)]];ones(1,3)])
>    den=1/dd;
>    Z=den*P(3)*(Y*vx-X*vy+det(M));%plane equ.
>    Zc=min(Zc,Z);Zc=max(Zc,Z1);
> end; 
> view([-29,36]);
> g=surf(X,Y,Zc);
> set(g,'edgecolor','none')
> ```

**Appendix :** A very straightforward way to obtain the analytical equation of the two angle bissectors of two lines with resp. equations $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$ is to express that a point $M(x,y)$ belongs to one of them iff its signed distance is the same to both of them, i.e.,

> $$\dfrac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\pm \dfrac{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$$

($\pm$ sign for distinguishing interior and exterior angle bissectors)

Answer (score 0):

You could approach such a problem systematically, which is also ideal for programming purpose.

Let $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ and $(x_3, y_3)$ be the three neighboring vertexes of a polygon. The angle bisecting line for the vertex $(x_2, y_2)$ can be derived as follows.

The slopes of the line going through $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is just

$$\tan\theta_1 = \frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$$

and for the line going through $(x_3, y_3)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$

$$\tan\theta_3 = \frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}$$

Then, the slope for the angle bisecting line of the vertex $(x_2, y_2)$ is

$$\tan\alpha_2 = \tan\frac{\theta_1+\theta_3}{2}=\frac{\tan(\theta_1/2)+\tan(\theta_3/2)}{1-\tan(\theta_1/2)\tan(\theta_3/2)}$$

Therefore, the bisector line for the vertex $(x_2,y_2)$ is

$$y-y_2=\tan(\alpha_2) (x-x_2)$$

The above derivation is then repeated to obtain bisector lines for all the vertexes.

The intersections among them can then be obtained by solving the intercepts of bisector line pairs. For example, the intersection point between the bisectors of vertexes $m$ and $n$ is the solution of the following system of linear equations,

$$y-y_m=\tan(\alpha_m) (x-x_m)$$

$$y-y_n=\tan(\alpha_n) (x-x_n)$$

Comment: Using tangents is to be avoided because rather often one has vertical segments with infinite tangents. See a classical method in the appendix to my answer.

Comment: Point taken ... ...